# Load new ArrayList in Android, depending on another Spinner

Tags: android-spinner

my problem is as following:

I have a few Spinner in Android.
With the first Spinner you can select a city.
Depending on the chosen city a second Spinner that was prefilled with 15, 30, 60, ... should be overwritten and filled with an another R.array.munich_minutes

I already created the Spinner, but I do not know how I can accomplish refilling the second Spinner with other values.

Here is my code

```
    spinnerCity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCity = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.city, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterCity.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCity.setAdapter(adapterCity);
    spinnerCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    spinnerMinutes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.vienna_minutes_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterMinutes = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.vienna_minutes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterMinutes.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerMinutes.setAdapter(adapterMinutes);
    spinnerMinutes.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnerMinutes.setEnabled(false);

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
      if(item.equals("Munich")) {
        //load R.array.munich_minutes
      }
    }
```

Thank you very much for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.
I was under a misconception - I thought that xml will be drawn as soon as I call it in the source code. The opposite is the case, in the source code I am just using the defined views and everything.

Here is the code:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    if(item.equals("Wien")) {
        spinnerMinutes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.minutes_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterMinutes = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.vienna_minutes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterMinutes.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerMinutes.setAdapter(adapterMinutes);
        spinnerMinutes.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    } else if(item.equals("Klagenfurt")) {
        spinnerMinutes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.minutes_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterMinutes = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.klagenfurt_minutes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterMinutes.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerMinutes.setAdapter(adapterMinutes);
        spinnerMinutes.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
}
```